# problems with touch events

Tags: jquery, ipad

Im trying to use a player on my site (that I didnt code). Anyway, the player has afew touch events built in with it that don't seem to respond when I try and test them using an ipad. The volume slider should be able to drag left and right and the music stream should be able to do the same thing but at the moment they arn't working.

```
   // seeking in the loaded track buffer
  $('.sc-time-span')
    .live('click', function(event) {
      scrub(this, event.pageX);
      return false;
    })
    .live('touchstart', function(event) {
      this.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
      event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    })
    .live('touchend', function(event) {
      this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
      event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    });

  // changing volume in the player
  var startVolumeTracking = function(node, startEvent) {
    var $node = $(node),
        originX = $node.offset().left,
        originWidth = $node.width(),
        getVolume = function(x) {
          return Math.floor(((x - originX)/originWidth)*100);
        },
        update = function(event) {
          $doc.trigger({type: 'scPlayer:onVolumeChange', volume: getVolume(event.pageX)});
        };
    $node.bind('mousemove.sc-player', update);
    update(startEvent);
  };

  var stopVolumeTracking = function(node, event) {
    $(node).unbind('mousemove.sc-player');
  };

  $('.sc-volume-slider')
    .live('mousedown', function(event) {
      startVolumeTracking(this, event);
    })
    .live('mouseup', function(event) {
      stopVolumeTracking(this, event);
    });

  $doc.bind('scPlayer:onVolumeChange', function(event) {
    $('span.sc-volume-status').css({width: event.volume + '%'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that since you're using jQuery's live() binding, but it may be relying on jQuery UI touch event plugin to work. If you include the plugin from http://touchpunch.furf.com/ it will probably solve your issue.